# Giving an externalloginlist button an imagine

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I was wondering how you would have an image as the actually button for the external logins like google and facebook.
I mean in this area where it says this in the AuthConfig.cs file

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
```

I'm sure there must be something that has to be passed into this method but I dont know what.  Also I have did some research and Zocial came up to design the necessary button I want but I'm not sure how to apply the css classes from Zocial to the externalloginlist action in the html when the code is like this.

```
 <section class="social" id="socialLoginForm">
 <h2>Use another service to log in.</h2>
 @Html.Action("ExternalLoginsList", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a textbox that is positioned in the minus margin-left, so it's  visible but cannot be seen by the user.

Then you give path of your background to this textbox and settimeinterval jquery to auto detect any change in this textbox and change background of div.

If this way is too long, you can simply bind a jQuery function where #your-div triggers background image change.

Comment: is there a way to call the img or to add a html class to externalloginlist ?

Comment: from css, no. for client-side coding, always use jQuery, ASP.NET is for server-side queries